# how to remove/delete the random data from disk which was created using if=dev/urandom

Tags: system, disk, diskspace

I think I did some stupid thing by creating random data using some command `dd if=/dev/urandom of=20GB.bin bs=1GB count=16 iflag=fullblock`
in huge size. Actually I was testing the behaviors of something when disk is full.

However Now I wish to delete this. I deleted the dev/urandom folder hoping it will do something, but it seems nothing was deleted without making any difference.

I see some commands online like `wipe` and `shred`, However now my dev/urandom folder is deleted, so what exactly should I do now ?

Any kind of help will be great.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment and help. I just edited by question again. I have written the exact command I used for huge file. The one I wrote earlier was for not exactly the one which created huge file. It was in few MBs only.

Answer (score 0):

you saved the random numbers to `20GB.bin` thus you can do `rm 20GB.bin` to remove it. `/dev/urandom` is a special file bound to a tool and does not save random files, but just creates them on the fly. Some other tools might depend on `/dev/urandom` so deleting this device file might let them crash.

Comment: Hi @danloo, Thanks for your response. may i know where exactly Can I find this file, it sayd `rm: cannot remove '20GB.bin': No such file or directory` when I try to run this

Comment: You must execute this command at the same working directory where you did the dd command, since you showed a relative file path.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again.
However, Is there any other way, I seem to have run this command few time ago. I don't exactly remember which folder I ran this command.

Comment: `find / | grep 20GB.bin`

Comment: Thanks a lot @danloo, I found this file using find and now have deleted it.
My issue has been solved. Thanks once again